# Detect silent install in .NET Custom Action

Tags: c#, windows-installer

How do you detect that the install is running in silent mode?

I have a custom application that I've added a .msi setup project.  I run the .msi file with the /qb switch, and in my custom installer c# code I would like to be able to detect this.

Edit: nobugs says to test the UILevel property. How do I access the UILevel property from a class derived from the System.Configuration.Install.Installer class?

Comment: What are you installing? C#?  Custom App?

Comment: I edited the question to state that it is a custom application that I've added a setup project to create the .msi installer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taking the hint from nobugz, I did the following:

1. On the Custom Actions view of the .msi setup project, I added the following to my CustomActionData (to pass the UILevel through to my custom installer):

   /UILevel="[UILevel]"
2. Within my C# code for the code derived from base class Installer, I added code to get the value:

   string uiLevelString = Context.Parameters["UILevel"];
3. It was then simple to parse the string for an int value. If the value is <= 3, it is a silent install.

Comment: could you please detail on step 2 - where exactly do you write that code, on which event of the derived class? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Andrei Cristof In step 2 I did an override of "Install" method.

Comment: Here is a helpful tutorial with screenshots: https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2009/11/13/how-to-detect-unattended-installation-msiexec-quit-or-qn-in-youre-custom-action-with-c/

Comment: It took me some time to find the CustomActionData setting. Right click on the project name in the Solution Explorer, and choose 'View->Custom Actions". Then select the action, and you should see CustomActionData in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

First I would point out that InstallUtil is a very bad pattern.  They run out of process, tatoo the process with a CLR version and when they fail they raise a 1001 error modal dialog even during a silent install.

Instead you should use WiX's DTF pattern.

MsiGetMode ( Session.Mode ) is limited during deferred execution so you will have to serialize and deserialize the UILevel.

http://www.msifaq.com/a/1044.htm