# detect quiet mode

Tags: windows, winforms

I need to be able to detect quiet mode in my setup project's class library. Some of library's methods show dialog forms, and they won't be visible if the setup is running in quiet mode. So I need to detect the quiet mode, or at least check if the windows forms can be displayed at all. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [UILevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372096.aspx) property of the Windows Installer.

Comment: How can I use it inside of my .NET class library? Can't find it as a part of the installer class or something.

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388530/detect-silent-install-in-net-custom-action